# ayuda con push.js

Tags: php, html, push-notification, push.js

tengo un help desk el cual quiero que cuando manden un "ticket" me aparezca una notificacion en el navegador, pero no he encontrado algo con que hacerla he probado con push.js pero ni siquiera puedo instalarlo ingreso por si lo necesitan donde se ingresa el ticket gracias

```html
<?php
include('is_logged.php');//Archivo verifica que el usario que intenta acceder a la URL esta logueado
// checking for minimum PHP version
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.7', '<')) {
    exit("Sorry, Simple PHP Login does not run on a PHP version smaller than 5.3.7 !");
} else if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.5.0', '<')) {
    // if you are using PHP 5.3 or PHP 5.4 you have to include the password_api_compatibility_library.php
    // (this library adds the PHP 5.5 password hashing functions to older versions of PHP)

}  
  if (empty($_POST['incidencia'])){
   $errors[] = "Por favor seleccione una incidencia";
  } elseif (empty($_POST['tema'])){
   $errors[] = "Tema vacío";
  }  elseif (empty($_POST['detalle'])) {
            $errors[] = "detalle vacío";
        } elseif (empty($_FILES['imagen']['name'])) {
      $errors[] = "imagen vacía";
        }  elseif (
   !empty($_POST['incidencia'])
            && !empty($_POST['tema'])
   && !empty($_POST['detalle'])
            && !empty($_FILES['imagen'])
        )  {
            require_once ("../config/db.php");
   require_once ("../config/conexion.php");
   
    
                $incidencia = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["incidencia"],ENT_QUOTES)));
    $tema = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["tema"],ENT_QUOTES)));
    $detalle = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["detalle"],ENT_QUOTES)));
                $imagen = ($_FILES['imagen']);
                $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["firstname"],ENT_QUOTES)));
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM ticket WHERE incidencia = '" . $incidencia . "' OR tema = '" . $tema . "';";
                $query_check_incidencia = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO ticket (incidencia, tema, detalle, firstname, imagen)
                            VALUES('".$incidencia."','".$tema."','" . $detalle . "','".$_SESSION['firstname']."','" . $_FILES['imagen']['name'] . "');";
           
                    $query_new_incidencia_insert = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$imagen = $_FILES['imagen']['name']; 
                    $ruta_tmp = $_FILES['imagen']['tmp_name'];
     $ruta_final = '../img/' . $imagen; 
                    if (!file_exists($ruta_final)) {
                    move_uploaded_file($ruta_tmp, $ruta_final);
        }
  }
            
         else {
            $errors[] = "Un error desconocido ocurrió.";
        }
  
  if (isset($errors)){
   
   ?>
   <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
     <strong>Error!</strong> 
     <?php
      foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo $error;
       }
      ?>
   </div>
   <?php
   }
   if (isset($messages)){
    
    ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
      <strong>¡Bien hecho!</strong>
      <?php
       foreach ($messages as $message) {
         echo $message;
        }
       ?>
    </div>
    <?php
               
   }

?>
```

PD: esta hecho en ajax

intento de codigo

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="push.js-master/src/push/Push.js">
    </script>
    <script>
Push.create("Hello world!", {
    body: "How's it hangin'?",
    icon: '/icon.png',
    timeout: 4000,
    onClick: function () {
        window.focus();
        this.close();
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: A clara algo: estas usuando push.js si o no? No veo referencia en parte de push.js. O es que quieres aprender a como utilizarlo?

Comment: quiero aprender a utilizarlo

Comment: Has intentado algo?

Comment: si ya pero el git hub cambio y ya no aparecen los archivos que hay que cargar en el head   ya lo agrego al codigo

Comment: Intenta este: `<script src="https://pushjs.org/scripts/push.min.js" ></script>`

Comment: listo ya ahora si "instalo"

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68419/discussion-between-einer-and-kevin-salazar).

Comment: hay alguna manera de hacerlo pero teniendo la pagina cerrada y cada vez que un usuario se registre en la base de datos?